# Flutterfire cli not showing windows as an option for platform to support

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, flutter-windows

The following error is thrown when I tried to run a windows application

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for windows - you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.
#0      DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform (package:user_authentication/firebase_options.dart:36:9)
#1      main (package:user_authentication/main.dart:11:37)
#2      _runMain.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:134:23)
#3      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
```

I even tried to run flutterfire configure command from the root directory
Flutterfire cli not showing windows as an option for platform to support

```
i Found 2 Firebase projects. Selecting project my-cool-firebase.
? Which platforms should your configuration support (use arrow keys & space to select)? ›
✔ android
  ios
  macos
✔ web
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try to run `flutter pub add firebase_core_desktop`

and then `flutterfire configure`

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core_desktop

Answer (score 1):

The entry for firebase_options that gets created for Windows is virtually identical to the one created for the web.  There are two alternative options.

(1) Use the web entry in the firebase_options file by updating the case statement

```
  case TargetPlatform.windows:
    return web;
```

(2) Clone the web entry and use it for the Windows entry but manually create a new appId in the Firebase Console in the Project Settings section and update the appId: tag in the cloned entry

Finally, many of the packages have been only recently updated for firebase desktop so you may want to check the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I am assuming when you run `flutterfire configure` command, it isn't showing windows & linux option. For some reason `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`  this command wasn't working for me. What solved my issue is

1. I Added `flutterfire_cli` package manually to pubspec.yaml using `flutter pub add flutterfire_cli`
2. Then I Run `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`

after you done those two steps, `flutterfire configure --project=<your-project-name>` should show windows and linux option.

Comment: This did not work for me.