# Flutterfire cli not showing windows as an option for platform to support while the official firebase packages started supporting windows (FINALLY)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

[Firebase_Auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) and [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) has finally released a new version that supports windows implementation. However in the Flutterfire cli there is no option for windows:

? Which platforms should your configuration support (use arrow keys & space to select)?

✔ android

✔ ios

✔ macos

✔ web

therefore when I try to run the app I obviously get an error :

> DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for windows - you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.

Is there any way to configure the windows app to use the official packages beside manual options Configuration?

Comment: See this question/answer which resolved the problem for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73842498/flutterfire-cli-not-showing-windows-as-an-option-for-platform-to-support?rq=2

Comment: See this question/answer which resolved the problem for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73842498/flutterfire-cli-not-showing-windows-as-an-option-for-platform-to-support?rq=2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

run `flutter pub add firebase_core_desktop`

and then run  `flutterfire configure`

The answer was posted in this question
[Flutterfire cli not showing windows as an option for platform to support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73842498/flutterfire-cli-not-showing-windows-as-an-option-for-platform-to-support?rq=2)

Comment: I just realised that the published version of firebase_core_desktop is not compatible with the latest packages needed for desktop use.  In this case, you might be better using the web entry for firebase options as the desktop entry